# Azure: Passing credentials to constructor of ComputeManagementClient requiring incorrect type

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm trying to deploy an azure cloud service and VM using the .NET SDK following the instructions on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722415.aspx.  I'm using the SDK version 2.6 (latest).

I'm having trouble creating the credential object to pass to the constructor of ComputeManagementClient.  The intellisense is attempting to validate the wrong type.

It expects:  Microsoft.Azure.SubscriptionCloudCredentials

What exists: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.SubscriptionCloudCredentials

As far as I can tell, there is no Microsoft.Azure namespace and this is a bug in the definition of the constructor of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.ComputeManagementClient.ComputeManagementClient

Does anyone have a suggestion?

(I've gone as far as follow, directly, the syntax described in the link above).

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
```

try

```
using Microsoft.Azure;
```

The second using statement is the one that contains the correct SubscriptionCloudCredentials object to use. It looks like the documentation is out-of-date (not uncommon).

Comment: Well that is embarrassing.  I also needed to add a reference to Microsoft.Azure.Common.  Thanks!

Comment: It happens... particularly with the pace at which this stuff moves.